# printf()/puts() after use of ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm using the `ncurses` library in a C project, and encountered a problem with the use of `printf()`/`puts()` after curses was initialized **and** de-initialized. Here's a simplified illustration:

```
initscr();
endwin();

puts("first");
usleep(1e6);
puts("second");
```

Both `first` and `second` will appear on the screen only after the containing executable exits (after a little over one second), instead of printing `first` first, and then, a second later, `second`. `ncurses` seems to be buffering `stdout` somehow and only flushing it on exit. `fflush(stdout)` seems to solve the problem:

```
initscr();
endwin();

puts("First.");
fflush(stdout);
usleep(1e6);
puts("Second");
```

When `stdout` is manually flushed, output is displayed as expected (with a second gap). If I were to add more `puts()` statements afterwards with `usleep()`s in between, though, I'd need to repeat the calls to `fflush(stdout)` after each one, and I'm wondering if there's a better solution that, say, permanently resets the program to pre-curses mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ncurses` calls `setvbuf`, putting streams to a full buffered mode. Either specify the environment variable `NCURSES_NO_SETBUF` to instruct it to not change buffering, or restore the buffer mode by calling `setvbuf` again, although `man 3 setvbuf` advises against this:

> The setvbuf() function may be used at any time, but may have peculiar side effects (such as discarding input or flushing output) if the stream is ``active''.  Portable applications should call it only once on any given stream, and before any I/O is performed.

Here is how to restore `stdout` to line-buffering and `stderr` to no buffering again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  initscr();
  endwin();

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
  setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  puts("First.");
  usleep(1e6);
  puts("Second");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, the suggested solution is unlikely to be portable.  Quoting (glibc's) manpage: "   The setvbuf()  function  may only be used after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it."

Comment: Referring to ncurses' changelog (http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t990213), other "peculiar side effects" include core dumps.